# Selecting joints by mouse click in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty new to ROS/gazebo and I need to select a joint with mouse click in gazebo (to let the user set its position or drag the joint to specific location by inverse kinematics). Is there any API to interpret 2D location of mouse click to 3D coordinate of world?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29786/selecting-joints-by-mouse-click-in-gazebo/) by [asixone](https://answers.ros.org/users/1976/asixone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do this via rviz: a good place to start could be to look at how it's done for the PR2 teleop via interactive markers: [pr2_marker_control](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_marker_control)

---

Originally posted by [TomTUM](https://answers.ros.org/users/547/tomtum/) with karma: 481 on 2012-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1